# Nothing happens when running my code [BigInteger]

Tags: java, biginteger

So I have a class that computes two prime numbers and then checks if they're prime

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class GeneratePrime{

  public static BigInteger calculatePPrime() {
    BigInteger pRandom;
    while (true) {
      pRandom = new BigInteger(512, new Random());
      pRandom = pRandom.setBit(0); 
      if(isPrime(pRandom)){
        System.out.println("Got Random Prime P: "+pRandom);
        break;
      }
    }
    return pRandom;
  }

  public static BigInteger calculateQPrime() {
    BigInteger qRandom;
    while(true){
      qRandom = new BigInteger(512, new Random());
      if(isPrime(qRandom)){
        System.out.println("Got Random Prime Q: "+qRandom);
        break;
      }
    }
    return qRandom;
  }

  public static boolean isPrime(BigInteger number) {
    if (!number.isProbablePrime(5))
        return false;

    BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
    if (!two.equals(number) && BigInteger.ZERO.equals(number.mod(two)))
        return false;

    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("3"); i.multiply(i).compareTo(number) < 1; i = i.add(two)) {
        if (BigInteger.ZERO.equals(number.mod(i)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

This is more or less a conglomerate of things I have found on the internet. This class was originally not using any BigIntegers, but then I found out I am required to use it for my assignment, so I had to scratch everything and do this.

Anyway. I can't use any built in functions to calculate primes (idk if there even are any). My issue here is that when I run this code in:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class RSA{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger p, q;
        GeneratePrime gp = new GeneratePrime();
        p = gp.calculatePPrime();
        q = gp.calculateQPrime();
    }
}
```

Both classes compile fine, but then when I run the RSA class, nothing happens. No errors no nothing. My terminal is just blank. Does anyone know why? Or can anyone see if this code works on their machine? I know I've probably missed something dumb here. Thanks

Comment: Most likely the program is busy looping in search for a prime number.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't duplicate code this way. Just have one `calculatePrime()` instead of `calculatePPrime()` and identical `calculateQPrime()`.

Comment: Maybe because the random numbers you are generating are very big (512 bits, that's about 154 decimal digits), so that the calculation takes very long? Computers are fast, but not so fast that they can do anything in a few seconds...

Comment: @OlafDietsche no it doesnt. it breaks properly. i tried the code and added counter. its ran a total of 100 loops

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that's probably because you've put the counter in calculatePrime but the CPU is busy looping in a single call to isPrime().

Comment: dont believe it. why would 300 clacs go within 1 sec and the 3001st would take hours?

Comment: actually the isPrime() always breaks at first if

Comment: I get different results. It always shows a lot of non prime numbers, and eventually it is busy in the for loop in `isPrime`.

Comment: Yep, the `isPrime` method is highly unefficient for large prime numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get random primes? Then make that clear in your code:

```
public BigInteger randomPrime(int bits, Random random) {
  return new BigInteger(bits, random).nextProbablePrime();
  // or
  // return BigInteger.probablePrime(bits, random);
}
```

Use the methods at your disposal, in this case: `nextProbablePrime()`. This method is so much more efficient than the set of methods you wrote. This will significantly boost your application.

Your RSA class can then become:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class RSA{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger p, q;
        GeneratePrime gp = new GeneratePrime();
        Random random = new Random();
        int bits = 512;
        p = gp.randomPrime(bits, random);
        q = gp.randomPrime(bits, random);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use the `512` bits number and you want to randomly get it and hope it will be a prime. You will find no success with your kind of solution. This is just too large value to be handled with too many possibilities. Even if you use the `BigInteger` constructor with `certainty` in. Like so :

```
new BigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random random);
```

Where the java doc says:

> `certainty` - a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is willing to tolerate. The probability that the new BigInteger represents a prime number will exceed (1 - 1/(2<sup>certainty</sup>)).

*The larger you make `certainty`, the smaller is the probablility that the number is not prime.*

Still will not help you. You can consider on some point of taking just the next prime number if the randomed one is not a prime as @Olivier Grégoire suggested or just reduce the number of bits.

Answer (score 0):

The value for maximum bitLength of the new BigInteger is very large. If you reduce it to a smaller number it will work. I'm referring to the value 512 in the code below. Try a small number like 12.

`pRandom = new BigInteger(512, new Random());`